# Difference between String + char and String + single char String

Tags: java

```
"ab" + 'c' // String + char
"ab" + "c" // String + String of single char
```

What is the difference between these expressions?

- Is there any impact on the performance?
- Is there any difference in behavior on different Java versions?

Comment: Querstions about performance on this level are basically pointless: The answer depends on so many factors (such as surrounding code, JVM version, JVM flags, ...) that no useful general answer can be given.

Comment: I believe `javac` interns those. Did you check the bytecode generated for the concatenations outcome with `javap`?

Comment: `char` type is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode. Use code point integer numbers or a `CharSequence` such as `String`.

Comment: @BasilBourque: "`char` type is obsolete" is misleading at best and straight up wrong at worst. It does has the problems you mention, but that doesn't mean that using it is always a wrong choice. Also, downvoting without posting a comment is perfectly acceptable on SO. There are no rules to force people to comment.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I never claimed any rule requiring a comment with a vote. I made a request. I don’t see the problem with this question, and asked for an explanation. Just as I would ask you how you use `char` to work with all of the 140,000 Unicode characters.

Comment: @BasilBourque: sometimes you don't **need** to work with all possible Unicode characters. When appending a hard-coded `:` or `<` or any other boring character to a string then a `char` constant does the job just fine. Yes, when iterating over a `String` you *usually* don't want to use `char` but even that depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using A + "B" is much slower than using A + 'B' based on this test result

[Concatenate char literal ('x') vs single char string literal (“x”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859500/concatenate-char-literal-x-vs-single-char-string-literal-x)

Test Result:

averageing to:

a+'B': 4608ms

a+"B": 5167ms

Comment: Constant expression will be optimized by compiler so there is no difference for performance. This answer is what I really searching.